# Data frame with different number of columns in a for loop

Tags: r

I am new to R and got stuck on a for loop for my web scraping project using rvest.
I am trying to extract notes (nested within scorecard URL) from ESPN cricinfo website. My code is this;

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

get_notes = function(score){
  score_page = read_html(score)
  score_notes = score_page %>% html_nodes(".ds-mt-3 .ds-mb-4 .ds-p-4,
                                            .ds-mb-4~ .ds-mb-4+ .ds-mb-4 .ds-p-4,
                                           .ds-mt-3 .ds-text-typo-title .ds-text-tight-s") %>% html_text()
}

notesdata = data.frame()

for (page_result in c(2019,2020,2021)){
  link = paste0("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=2;id=",
                 page_result,";type=year")
  pages = read_html(link)
  
  
  scorecard = pages %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(7) .data-link") %>% html_text()
  match_url = pages %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(7) .data-link") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste("https://www.espncricinfo.com/",., sep="") 
  
  notes = sapply(match_url, FUN = get_notes, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  
  notesdata = rbind(notesdata,
                             data.frame(t(notes),
                                        desperse.level = 0)
  )

  
  print(paste("page:", page_result))
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message;

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Can someone help me create a data frame (or anything that I can turn into csv file)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to run your "reproducible" example due to the `oget_notes` function returns very large matrices. However, I think that your problem would be associated with the next:

```
onotes = sapply(omatch_url, FUN = oget_notes, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

1. That line returns a matrix of dimensions 3xL, where L is the length of `omatch_url`.
2. The other objects (`oteam_one`, `oteam_two`, `oMatch_dates`, `oground` and `oscorecard`) are of length L.
3. When you try to run `data.frame(oteam_one,oteam_two,oMatch_dates,oground,oscorecard,onotes)`, the  `data.frame` function is expecting a vector of some same length (L) or matrices with as many rows as the length of the vectors (L x #).

So, my suggestion would be to change your line 32 from this:

```
onotesdata = rbind(onotesdata,
                   data.frame(oteam_one,
                              oteam_two,
                              oMatch_dates,
                              oground,
                              oscorecard,
                              onotes))
```

To this:

```
onotesdata = rbind(onotesdata,
                       data.frame(oteam_one,
                                  oteam_two,
                                  oMatch_dates,
                                  oground,
                                  oscorecard,
                                  t(onotes)), 
             deparse.level = 0)
```

Again, I couldn't run your script because the output of `oget_notes`, so I don't know if this solution will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggestion and there was a bit of a progress, but the error message is now; "" Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match"". How can I clean this data? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Futa I have eddited my answer including two changes (over functions `sapply` and `rbind`) that should help for avoiding name missmatching.

Comment: I still get the same error message...

Comment: @Futa Well, it would be useful (for me at least) if you could make an easy-to-run reproducible example. I mean, some piece of code that replicates the error that you have but with less URLs to read.

Comment: I updated my original question to more reproducible code. Could you take another look? Thank you so much. Sorry for the messy code. I am new to both R and Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Futa When `page_result` is `2020`, `notes` is a list whose elements have whether 1 or 3 elements. So, `sapply` could not simplify it as a matrix, because it would require that every element would have the same length (3). In summary, you have to check your function `get_notes` and try to do something regarding with the cases when the output is just the one element `"MATCH DETAILS"` (completing with `NA` maybe?). I could not suggest the modification because it depends on you (you only know what are you doing and what are you expecting for).

Comment: I see thank you so much! I will try filling it in with NA.